# vue: Wrong type check for prop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My component has in data section:

```
photos: ['images/1.jpg','images/2.jpg']
```

In template (pug) :

```
 ...
 v-carousel
     v-carousel-item(v-for='(item,i) in photos',:key='i',
       :src='item')
```

It works ok but got 2 warnings:

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, got Number.
found in --->

If

```
 :src='item'
```

change to

```
 :src='item.toString()'
```

there are no warnings.

Is it Vue or Vuetify or my error?

Comment: >>  Belmin Bedak Nope, it works, just wrong warnings.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with the information you've provided https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVbOZP

Comment: It is possible the problem in my path format something/{number}.jpg. Or dipper https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1678 and it is just consequence,

Comment: Using the `photos` array in your example. The images don't load, obvious, but I don't get the error you describe. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bobrby

Comment: As I said it works and probably the warning arises after displaying a image. Anyway it is a small problem, just a warning.   The error github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1678 does not allow me to use the component for my case yet.